# python Code that send messages received in specific channels of discord channel as text message to phone

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

I have subscribed to the channel in discord. sometimes I am missing messages in that discord, is there a code that sends that messages from a specific channels in discord to the phone via sms?

Answer (score 1):

There is.

https://github.com/leogomezz4t/PyTextNow_API

PyTextNow enables you to send SMS from Python. To do this you would do something like:

```
import discord
import pytextnow

client = discord.Client()
text = pytextnow.Client("username", sid_cookie="sid", srf_cookie="csrf")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  text.send_sms('number',message.content)
```

Be sure to read the pytextnow and Discord documentation.

Comment: Is PyTextNow working for you? Because I am unable to login using pytextnow.client() for some reason.